# Find continuous range in a list of unicode code points

Tags: unicode, codepoint, unicode-range

I have a list of unicode code points, something along these lines (*not an actual set, problem illustration only*):

```
uni050B
uni050C
uni050D
uni050E
uni050F
uni0510
uni0511
uni0512
uni0513
uni1E00
uni1E01
uni1E3E
uni1E3F
uni1E80
uni1E81
uni1E82
uni1E83
uni1E84
uni1E85
uni1EA0
and so forth…
```

I need to find the [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) for these. Some parts of this set are continuous, with some points missing - so the range is not `U+050B-1EA0`.
Is there a sensible way of extracting those continuous "sub-ranges"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but possibly you are not working with *Unicode code points* but with glyphs (so with usual complication). Font handling libraries and tools may help in such case. An additional note: your question in not fully clear: what are you asking? A generic algorithm is trivial, but possibly you are looking for specific language and library? In such case, it is useful to include the relative language tag in question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything "off-the-shelf" but easy enough to calculate.  Below finds consecutive numbers and builds a `unicode-range` using Python:

```py
import re

def build_range(uni):
    '''Pass a list of sorted positive integers to include in the unicode-range.
    '''
    uni.append(-1) # sentinel prevents having to special case the last element
    start,uni = uni[0],uni[1:]
    current = start

    strings = []
    for u in uni:
        if u == current: # in case of duplicates
            continue
        if u == current + 1: # in a consecutive range...
            current = u
        elif start == current: # single element
            strings.append(f'U+{current:X}')
            start = current = u
        else: # range
            strings.append(f'U+{start:X}-{current:X}')
            start = current = u
        
    return 'unicode-range: ' + ', '.join(strings) + ';'

data = '''\
uni050B
uni050C
uni050D
uni050E
uni050F
uni0510
uni0511
uni0512
uni0513
uni1E00
uni1E01
uni1E3E
uni1E3F
uni1E80
uni1E81
uni1E82
uni1E83
uni1E84
uni1E85
uni1EA0'''

# parse out the hexadecimal values into an integer list
uni = sorted([int(x,16) for x in re.findall(r'uni([0-9A-F]{4})',data)])

print(build_range(uni))
```

Output:

```
unicode-range: U+50B-513, U+1E00-1E01, U+1E3E-1E3F, U+1E80-1E85, U+1EA0;
```